# Python script add values to make output consistent

Tags: python, web-scraping

I found this script on stackoverflow to to get some data from understat. (Its made or modified by @chitown88 I think so credits to him/her).

The output is like this

```
  League Season                         Date         Home team      Away team    0    1    2    3    4    5    6         7         8         9        10        11        12        13        14       15       16       17        18        19        20        21        22        23        24        25        26        27        28        29        30        31        32        33        34        35        36        37        38        39        40        41        42       43       44       45       46        47        48        49        50        51        52        53        54        55        56        57        58        59        60        61        62        63        64        65        66        67        68        69        70        71        72        73        74        75        76        77        78        79        80        81        82        83        84        85    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30        31        32        33        34        35        36        37        38        39        40        41        42        43        44        45        46        47        48        49        50        51        52        53        54        55        56        57        58        59        60        61        62        63        64        65        66        67        68        69        70        71        72        73        74        75        76        77        78        79        80        81        82        83        84        85
0    EPL   2018  Saturday, February 23, 2019  Newcastle United  Huddersfield*  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.087855  0.087855  0.087855  0.087855  0.474551  0.474551  0.474551  0.474551  0.52089  0.52089  0.52089  0.588242  0.588242  0.588242  0.588242  0.588242  0.588242  0.588242  0.650563  0.650563  0.650563  0.713521  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.780235  0.862191  0.862191  0.862191  0.972581  1.00803  1.00803  2.01324  2.01324  2.103931  2.103931  2.103931  2.103931  2.248354  2.248354  2.248354  2.278213  2.278213  2.278213  2.278213  2.278213  2.278213  2.397133  2.397133  2.397133  2.397133  2.397133  2.397133  2.484387  2.484387  2.624275  2.624275  2.755339  2.868987  2.868987  2.868987  2.868987  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.026651  3.026651  3.026651  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.133949
```

When doing this on multiple URLs, the time data is inconsistent i.e. some end at 83, some at 89, 90, 92 etc.

Any way I can modify this to get Time from 0 to 90 every single time?

If data ends at 83, maybe we can repeat xG values from 84-90?

Is this possible?

Here is the script:

```
import requests
import json
import re
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import pandas as pd

response = requests.get('https://understat.com/match/9458')

shotsData = re.search("shotsData\s+=\s+JSON.parse\('([^']+)", response.text)
decoded_string = bytes(shotsData.groups()[0], 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
shotsObj = json.loads(decoded_string)

match_info = re.search("match_info\s+=\s+JSON.parse\('([^']+)", response.text)
decoded_string = bytes(match_info.groups()[0], 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
matchObj = json.loads(decoded_string)


rostersData = re.search("rostersData\s+=\s+JSON.parse\('([^']+)", response.text)
decoded_string = bytes(rostersData.groups()[0], 'utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
rostersObj = json.loads(decoded_string)


# Shots Data into a DataFrame
away_shots_df = json_normalize(shotsObj['a'])
home_shots_df = json_normalize(shotsObj['h'])
shots_df = away_shots_df.append(home_shots_df)



# Rosters Data into a DataFrame
away_rosters_df = pd.DataFrame()
for key, v in rostersObj['a'].items():
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([v])
    away_rosters_df = away_rosters_df.append(temp_df)



home_rosters_df = pd.DataFrame()
for key, v in rostersObj['h'].items():
    temp_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([v])
    home_rosters_df = home_rosters_df.append(temp_df)    

rosters_df = away_rosters_df.append(home_rosters_df) 


if away_rosters_df['red_card'].astype(int).sum() > 0:
    a_red_card = '*'
else:
    a_red_card = ''


if home_rosters_df['red_card'].astype(int).sum() > 0:
    h_red_card = '*'
else:
    h_red_card = ''

teams_dict = {'a':matchObj['team_a']+a_red_card, 'h':matchObj['team_h']+h_red_card}
match_title = matchObj['team_h'] + ' vs. ' + matchObj['team_a']


#########################################################################
# Timing Chart is an aggregation (running sum) of xG from the shotsData
#########################################################################
import numpy as np

# Convert 'minute' astype int and sort the dataframe by 'minute'
shots_df['minute'] = shots_df['minute'].astype(int)
shots_df['xG'] = shots_df['xG'].astype(float)

timing_chart_df = shots_df[['h_a', 'minute', 'xG']].sort_values('minute')
timing_chart_df['h_a'] = timing_chart_df['h_a'].map(teams_dict)

# Get max value of the 'minute' column to interpolate minute interval between that range
max_value = timing_chart_df['minute'].max()

# Aggregate xG within the same minute
timing_chart_df = timing_chart_df.groupby(['h_a','minute'], as_index=False)['xG'].sum()

# Interpolate for each team/group
min_idx = np.arange(timing_chart_df['minute'].max() + 1)
m_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([timing_chart_df['h_a'].unique(), min_idx], names=['h_a', 'minute'])


# Calculate the running sum
timing_chart_df = timing_chart_df.set_index(['h_a', 'minute']).reindex(m_idx, fill_value=0).reset_index()
timing_chart_df['running_sum_xG'] = timing_chart_df.groupby('h_a')['xG'].cumsum()


timing_chart_T_df = timing_chart_df.pivot(index='h_a', columns='minute', values='running_sum_xG')
timing_chart_T_df = timing_chart_T_df.reset_index().rename(columns={timing_chart_T_df.index.name:match_title})


from datetime import datetime

home_team = matchObj['team_h']+h_red_card
away_team = matchObj['team_a']+a_red_card

league = matchObj['league']
season = matchObj['season']
date = matchObj['date']
datetime_object = datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
date = datetime_object.strftime('%A, %B %d, %Y')

results_df = pd.DataFrame([[league, season, date, home_team, away_team]], columns = ['League','Season','Date','Home team','Away team'])

home_xg_sum = timing_chart_df[timing_chart_df['h_a'] == home_team].pivot(index='h_a', columns='minute', values='running_sum_xG')
away_xg_sum = timing_chart_df[timing_chart_df['h_a'] == away_team].pivot(index='h_a', columns='minute', values='running_sum_xG')



data = [league, season, date, home_team, away_team] + home_xg_sum.values.tolist()[0] + away_xg_sum.values.tolist()[0]
cols =  ['League','Season','Date','Home team','Away team'] + list(home_xg_sum.columns) + list(away_xg_sum.columns)


results_df = pd.DataFrame([data], columns = cols)
```

Comment: well the time data will be inconsistent since in football (soccer) the time counts up and does not stop, so you'll get extra time to account for stoppages. So if you do have a set cutoff (of say 90 minutes), you'll be throwing data away. It can be done, but is that really what you want?

Comment: for the times ending before 90, just basically means there were no xG between that last time and the end of the match. So actually, that would make sense to extend anything less than 90 to 90, and just have no change in the xG sum to that point.

Comment: Yeah that would be great actually. 90 mins for all matches and extended for ones that went into overtime.

Comment: ok, just added it below. any other questions, just let me know. I love working and playing with sports data

Comment: will this update extend the 90 mins for matches that go in overtime?

Comment: no, it'll stop at 90. So anything over 90 gets cut off. would you like it to always end at atleast 90? So if minutes are short of 90, extend to 90. If it's over 90, leave as is?

Comment: yes that'll be perfect. at least 90 for matches that are under 90 mins and over 90 for matches that went beyond.

Comment: ok. updated. just use a simple `if` statement. ie (if the max_value is less than 90, set it 90) otherwise if it's 90 or above, it'll just leave the max_value as that number. so that should take care of that.

Comment: cheers mate. will check it out later.

Answer (score 2):

Someone actually used my code! Well the way this script is setup isn't exactly how I'd arrange the output, but it's what the OP asked help with.

As far as changing that list of minutes to have a hard cut-off at 90, it's 1 line to change (and actually its 2 lines here. I didn't realize I had not used that variable in the line that should have used it). But change:

```
# Get max value of the 'minute' column to interpolate minute interval between that range
max_value = timing_chart_df['minute'].max()
```

to

```
# Get max value of the 'minute' column to interpolate minute interval between that range
max_value = timing_chart_df['minute'].max()
if max_value < 90:
    max_value = 90
```

and then a few lines below should reference that `max_value` variable, which I originally did not do. So change:

```
# Interpolate for each team/group
min_idx = np.arange(timing_chart_df['minute'].max() + 1)
```

to

```
# Interpolate for each team/group
min_idx = np.arange(max_value + 1)
```

**Output:**

```
print (results_df.to_string())
  League Season                         Date         Home team      Away team    0    1    2    3    4    5    6         7         8         9        10        11        12        13        14       15       16       17        18        19        20        21        22        23        24        25        26        27        28        29        30        31        32        33        34        35        36        37        38        39        40        41        42       43       44       45       46        47        48        49        50        51        52        53        54        55        56        57        58        59        60        61        62        63        64        65        66        67        68        69        70        71        72        73        74        75        76        77        78        79        80        81        82        83        84        85        86        87        88        89        90    0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30        31        32        33        34        35        36        37        38        39        40        41        42        43        44        45        46        47        48        49        50        51        52        53        54        55        56        57        58        59        60        61        62        63        64        65        66        67        68        69        70        71        72        73        74        75        76        77        78        79        80        81        82        83        84        85        86        87        88        89        90
0    EPL   2018  Saturday, February 23, 2019  Newcastle United  Huddersfield*  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.087855  0.087855  0.087855  0.087855  0.474551  0.474551  0.474551  0.474551  0.52089  0.52089  0.52089  0.588242  0.588242  0.588242  0.588242  0.588242  0.588242  0.588242  0.650563  0.650563  0.650563  0.713521  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.765269  0.780235  0.862191  0.862191  0.862191  0.972581  1.00803  1.00803  2.01324  2.01324  2.103931  2.103931  2.103931  2.103931  2.248354  2.248354  2.248354  2.278213  2.278213  2.278213  2.278213  2.278213  2.278213  2.397133  2.397133  2.397133  2.397133  2.397133  2.397133  2.484387  2.484387  2.624275  2.624275  2.755339  2.868987  2.868987  2.868987  2.868987  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.011753  3.026651  3.026651  3.026651  3.026651  3.026651  3.026651  3.026651  3.026651  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.110397  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.120421  0.133949  0.133949  0.133949  0.133949  0.133949  0.133949
```